# Activate checkout step by product category

Tags: magento, filter, categories, checkout

I would like to activate a certain extra step I have prepared in the onepage checkout stage only when products that belong to certain categories are added to the basket.

How can I set this filter using php code?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do it to following this guide:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step

in this method you need to extend/override `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage::getSteps()` to add your new step in the sequence.

Create your new step's block/template (loaded using an Ajax request when the previous step is completed) Your block class will need to extend: `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract`

You also need to extend the onepagecheckout javascript as this does much of the heavy lifting. The Prototype library has a nice way of doing this.

At the end you will need to extend the controller class `(Mage_Checkout_OnepageController)` to override the responses of any existing steps, return the content of your new step (loaded using ajax), and handle the save action of any data (form fields etc) entered in your new step

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I still have my question unanswered regarding the way to code the filter itself to have the step activated only when the product added to the shopping cart belongs to a certain category or not... The new step is already added and works perfectly. The only problem is the trigger...

Comment: you can check here with js http://snipplr.com/view/59607/ and call it if your cart content specific product category

Comment: Sorry Liyakay, I'm not able to find out the way to do this with that directions. Please, can you give me an example code? If product belongs to category a or b, then this step shall appear, otherwise, get rid of it and show the next one.

Comment: sorry for late anwer http://magentostriker.blogspot.in/2012/08/get-all-cart-product-categories-in.html check this link to verify cart product is from your category then load your extra steps on one page checkout

Comment: Dear Liyakay, I have this in my onepage.phtml file: